# How can i convert this matrix into a tree map using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a Matrix map but just realized I need a treemap, I am not able to find any simple example so that I can convert this code to make it a treemap with each box zoomable, putting me in right direction would be helpful,

**Code**

```
var rects = [
    [0, 0, "#C0FC3E"],
    [0, 200, "#60FC60"],
    [0, 400, "#64FE2E"],
    [0, 600, "#00FF00"],
    [200, 0, "#F6FF33"],
    [200, 200, "#AFFC3B"],
    [200, 400, "#00FF00"],
    [200, 600, "#64FE2E"],
    [400, 0, "#FDB500"],
    [400, 200, "#8DB723"],
    [400, 400, "#AFFC3B"],
    [400, 600, "#60FC60"],
    [600, 0, "red"],
    [600, 200, "#FDB500"],
    [600, 400, "#F6FF33"],
    [600, 600, "#C0FC3E"]
];

var width = 800,
    height = 800,
    boxWidth = 200,
    boxHeight = 200;
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var len = rects.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    CreateRect(rects[i][0], rects[i][1], rects[i][2])
}

svgContainer.append("text")
    .attr("x", 85)
    .attr("y", 125)
    .attr("font-size", 55)
    .text("3")
    .attr("onclick", "alert('You clicked A');");

function CreateRect(x, y, boxColor) {
    svgContainer.append("rect")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("width", boxWidth)
        .attr("height", boxHeight)
        .attr("fill", boxColor);
}
```

Here is JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9s7x0yuo/1/

Trying to follow this video but it all goes over my head - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svT9RdyQlrw

Reason I want to make it a heatmap is so that I can zoom into each rectangle box.

Comment: why dont you just call a zoom function on each individual rectangle ?

Comment: That's not what I am after, Treemap works different them zoom function

Comment: so you need a treeMap not a heatMap like you've put in the question lol ?